# Insufficient privileges в SonarQube

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, sonarqube, appveyor

Пытаюсь подключить SonarQube к проекту на c#. 
Закоммитил такой `appveyor.yml` (согласно [данной статье](https://www.appveyor.com/blog/)):

```
before_build:
  - nuget restore
build_script:
  - choco install "msbuild-sonarqube-runner" -y
  - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyProjectKey" /d:"sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com" /d:"sonar.login=MY_TOKEN"
  - msbuild "NeuralNetworkConstructor.sln"
  - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end /d:"sonar.login=MY_TOKEN"
```

Часть лога билда:

```
...
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
INFO: 9 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 8 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 156ms, dir size=101 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 47ms, zip size=59 KB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 22.312s
INFO: Final Memory: 68M/164M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Insufficient privileges <<==============================
...
```

P.S. Не совсем относится к вопросу, но я был бы благодарен за подсказку неплохих сервисов для .net проектов которые можно использовать вместе с appveyor. Я знаю, что есть еще travis-ci, но он через mono. Меня смущает "ничего не обещаем" в плане работоспособности.

Comment: Вынесите постскриптум в отдельный вопрос (четко сформулировав, какие именно сервисы вам нужны), либо сходите с ним в чат.

Comment: По поводу основного вопроса: проверьте права, как указано тут -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560807/1985167

Comment: Я немного не могу разобраться. Вот у меня есть 2 "организации", одна создалась, видимо, автоматически. Вторую создал я, и там создал проект указав ветку master (из другой ветки анализировать не будет?). При этом в конфиге appveyor я не указываю ни организацию ни проект. Попробовал установить SonarLint - вот это уже явно биндит проекты и солюшн между собой. Создавая файлы конфигурации для каждого проекта (тесты и основной код). Их нужно коммитить? Не коммитив перепроверил права в проекте. Для владельцев организации стоят все права. Мой Login@github является владельцем.

Comment: *указав ветку master (из другой ветки анализировать не будет?)* -- будет, если коммит в другой ветке и она не отфильтрована как описано [тут](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/branches/). То что Вы указали это просто ветка по умолчанию, и она используется если запускать руками, через API или по расписанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Нужно было просто действовать по [инструкции которую предлагает сам сервис SonarQube](https://about.sonarcloud.io/get-started/). Почему-то не наткнулся на нее сразу.
В моём конкретном случае, я неправильно понял поле `/k:"MyProjectKey"` и не вбил ключ организации.
Итоговый `appveyor.yml`:

```
before_build:
  - nuget restore
build_script:
  - choco install "msbuild-sonarqube-runner" -y
  - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"my-project-key" /d:"sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.com" /d:"sonar.organization=organization-key" /d:"sonar.login=TOKEN"
  - msbuild "NeuralNetworkConstructor.sln"
  - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end /d:"sonar.login=TOKEN"
```